# If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $f(x_0)>M$, then $f(x)>M$ in some neighborhood of $x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $f(x_0)>M$, then $f(x)>M$ for all $x$ some neighborhood of $x_0$.

My attempt is below.

From the assumptions above, we have that $f(x_0) > M = f(x_1)$ for some $x_1$ that $f$ is defined. Suppose that $x_0 > x_1$, then take $\delta >0$ such that $x_1\not\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, which gives $f(x) >f(x_1) = M\ \forall x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Does this hold? I feel like there is a better approach to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f(x)=M+a$ for some $a>0$, and if there exists a sequence $x_n\to x$
such that $f(x_n)\leq M$ for any $n$, then $f(x_n)\not\to f(x)$...

Actually your proof requires some more details, since you do not say how $x_1$ is chosen (if $x_1,\delta$ are not chosen carefully, you do not have $f(x)>M$ for any $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, having $x_1\notin (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ is not sufficient).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand your comment. Also, we cannot use any topological results. This is strictly an Intro to Real-Analysis course.  We have not touched on convergence or sequences, so I cannot use that approach.

Comment: it is by definition of continuity: for any sequence $x_n\to x$ it holds $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ (in other words $\lim_{y\to x}f(y)=f(x)$). You need more details since $x_1$ has to be chosen somewhat "close" to $x_0$, and $\delta$ "small" (otherwise consider $f(x)=\sin x$, $f(\pi/2)>0$, $f(-4\pi)=0$, $\delta = 2\pi$ is allowed by what you wrote, but you do not have $f(x)>0$ for any $x\in (\pi/2-2\pi,\pi/2+2\pi)$)

Comment: What if I specify and also add that condition that we pick an $\epsilon$ such that $M\not\in(f(x_0)-\epsilon,f(x_0)+\epsilon)$, which will give a $\delta >0$ such that $x_1\not\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, which should be a valid assumption since $f$ is continuous at $x_0.

Comment: That completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How $f(x_0)>M$ then  choice $\epsilon\leq (f(x_0)-M)$, in the definition of continuity in the form $\epsilon-\delta$

Note that as $f$ is continuous in $x_0$:  $\forall x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon\leq f(x_0)-M$
then:

$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|<f(x_0)-M\Longrightarrow|f(x_0)-f(x)|<f(x_0)-M$$
then
$$-f(x_0)+M<f(x_0)-f(x)<f(x_0)-M\Longrightarrow f(x)>M\quad \forall x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$$